# When exactly does the velocity of a cart change?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, conservation-laws

I have done many problems where where a small body is thrown from a moving cart and we have to use conservation of momentum to find the final velocities of the cart and the thrown object. To find the velocity of the thrown body with respect to the ground frame, we have to add the velocity with which it is thrown and velocity of the cart with respect to the ground. But in this scenario we always add the final velocity of the cart, not the initial velocity. Why is it so?

Comment: From my experience of such problems, I always had to add the initial velocity. Can you give an example of a source where they added the final velocity?

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient Here's problem 156 from the mechanics portion of irodov's physics book. All the solutions online have used final velocity.  "Two men, each of mass m, stand on the edge of a stationary
buggy of mass M. Assuming the friction to be negligible, find the
velocity of the buggy after both men jump off with the same horizontal velocity u relative to the buggy: (1) simultaneously; (2) one
after the other. In what case will the velocity of the buggy be greater
and how many times?"

Answer (score 1):

The cart does not accelerate further after the men jump. The same goes for the men. So just as the men leave the cart, it's velocity is $v_f$. That's why you add the final velocity and not the initial one.